# How do I take input and make sure it's a valid double number?

Tags: kotlin, input, types, double

My attempt so far:

```
var oneNum: Double
print("The first number: ");
oneNum = read.nextDouble()
```

If user enters anything other than numbers and a one dot the program will crash. I tried searching in google but I didn't find anything useful.

I tried to do it the long hard way by taking the input as string in `readLine()` and checking for anything other than numbers and then checking if there's more than one fraction dot(.) and if both conditions are true, I continue to convert the string to numbers and got stuck. This seems too complicated.

Answer (score 3):

Can be done in multiple ways, but the simplest form that I can think of would be this:

```
println("The first number: ");
val ourDouble = readLine()?.toDoubleOrNull() ?: error("You need to enter a double")
```

The `readLine()` will get the next thing you type in the console. It can be `null` if you give the input is a "end of file" character.

Thus we do `.?` which means proceed if this is not `null`.

The `toDoubleOrNull()` will attempt to transform the "String" input into a `Double`, if it fails, it will return `null`.

The elvis operator `?:` will only process what is on the right of it, if the left side is `null`. So it will only print the error if the `readLine()` is `null`, or if the `toDoubleOrNull()` is `null`.

Note: `error("message")` is the same as doing `throw Exeption("message")`.

---

Read the question again, since you want to keep the user in a purgatory until they input a double, you can create a function like this:

```
fun fetchDoubleFromUser(): Double {
    println("The first number:");
    return readLine()?.toDoubleOrNull()
            ?: run {
                println("You need to enter a double")
                fetchDoubleFromUser()
            }
}
```

or a simple `while`

```
fun fetchDoubleFromUser(): Double {
    println("The first number:");
    var ourNumber: Double? = null
    while (ourNumber == null) {
        ourNumber = readLine()?.toDoubleOrNull()
        ourNumber ?: println("You need to enter a double")
    }
    return ourNumber
}
```